# Get distinct value from join query (Join Table)

Tags: mysql, join

How get a distinct value form more than one table (inner join query).

Eg,

```
select a.id,b.name,c.address 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on (a.id = b.row_id)
inner join table3 c on (a.id = c.ticket_id)
where c.status = 'open';
```

Here the scenario is for example, two rows contain the same a.id value so how to get the distinct value from a.id.

Somebody help me that how to get?

Answer (score 1):

just add Distinct ...

```
select DISTINCT a.id,b.name,c.address 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on (a.id = b.row_id)
inner join table3 c on (a.id = c.ticket_id)
where c.status = 'open';
```

i think this is works fine..

if you need only one record distinct then it should be like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cat_id) FROM PRODUCTS WHERE brand_id = 'sony'
```

Comment: No for example, if the id 1 contain two address means it shows two rows but i need only the last address(only one row).